Configuring Python Build Slaves without root privilege, but allowing install during build job
I have run into a bit of a chicken and egg issue. The organisation that I worked for use a setup where they setup a docker build slave to be used in Jenkins to serve as a base image where CICD is run.
There is no issue running any installation in this slave image as I can use USER root to python -m pip install all the standard packages and after that revert back to USER jenkins.
The issue comes in when this base image is used during the actual build for applications. these applications may have their own requirements.txt where during build will have to be installed. As USER jenkins, I do not have permission to install any packages in the requirements.txt.
example,
If I try to run
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
I will get an error, for example:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/app-root/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel'
I guess I could use USER root to run the container, but it would be a really bad idea as this opens up security flaw and anyone with access to this build image "might" have privilege escalation to the underlying node running the slave.
And I don't really want to limit the users to only be able to install packages during the setup of the Build Slave image.
Any advice would be appreciated.

I'm guessing you don't use venv (and inside a container you don't have to). In that case you could do a "user install":
python -m pip install --user -r requirements.txt

No root access required, as opposed to "system install".
